# BlackBerry Table QML

Tags: blackberry-10

How to use the Table Component in BlackBerry 10?

I am having an `ImageView` and `Label`.

By default in the `Container` they are set one on top of another. So instead of the following preview I want to place them horizontally aligned.

```
Container {

            ImageView {
                       imageSource: "asset:///images/image.png"
                       }
                        Label {
                                preferredHeight: 200
                                text: "Simple Text"

                            }  
                        }
```

And the output of this code is

[Image]

[Text]

and I want to place them as

[Image] [Text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your container you need to add an orientation for left to right.

Here would be the example for your code above:

```
Container {
        layout: StackLayout {
            orientation: LayoutOrientation.LeftToRight
        }

        ImageView {
                   imageSource: "asset:///images/image.png"
                   }
                    Label {
                            preferredHeight: 200
                            text: "Simple Text"

                   }  
}
```